# JSDoc: how to hint this.constructor.staticSomething?

Tags: javascript, constructor, static-methods, jsdoc, anonymous-class

I am calling a static method from the constructor of an anonymous javascript class using `this.constructor.coords()`, but the returned type is not being recognized correctly. It is treated as `any`.

I know I can cast just cast it manually as `{x: number; y: number;}[]`, but I wonder if there is a smarter way to make VSCode/JSDoc just notice that the type of `this.constructor.something` must be that of the corresponding static method or property. Alternatively, I wonder if it is possible in JSDoc to cast `this.cls = this.constructor` with the anonymous class type (without giving it a name), because that would solve the problem for `this.constructor.something` as well.

```js
MyAnonymousClass = class {

  static coords(){
    return [{x:0, y:1}, {x:1, y:0}, {x:-1, y:-1}];
  }
  /* type of coords (on mouse hover in vsCode):
    (method) MyAnonymousClass.coords(): {
      x: number;
      y: number;
    }[] */ // (CORRECT)

  constructor(){
    const x = this.constructor.coords();
    // type of x (on mouse hover in vsCode): any // (INCORRECT)

  }
}
AnotherAnonymousClass = class extends MyAnonymousClass{
  static coords(){
    return [{x:0, y:2}, {x:-2, y:0}];
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `const x = MyAnonymousClass.coords();` should work.

Comment:  this fixes the type, but it changes the behavior, because in that case, `AnotherAnonymousClass` will not call its own coords method when instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick. I've just wrapped the class declaration around an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) so it's never accessible outside. It's like an anonymous class.

```js
const MyAnonymousClass = (() => {
    return class _ {
        static coords() {
            return [{ x: 0, y: 1 }, { x: 1, y: 0 }, { x: -1, y: -1 }];
        }

        constructor() {
            const x = /** @type {typeof _} */(this.constructor).coords();
        }

        foo() { }
    }
})();

const AnotherAnonymousClass = class extends MyAnonymousClass {
    static coords() {
        return [{ x: 0, y: 2 }, { x: -2, y: 0 }];
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]